# Combobox with macro on selecting items

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I'm very new to VBA and i searched and searched on Google, but can't find an example which deals with my problem.

I got a list of names which I want to put inside a selectable dropdownlist. When i click their name I want to run a different macro i made with their name on.
I tried a lot of things yesterday, but everytime it only succed me to assign 1 macro which was called no matter which name i pressed.

I think the solution is pretty simple, but i really got no clue how to do this the most simple way. So hopefully any of you got a link to a simple tutorial or can explain it to me in steps.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I got 2 names.
Birgitte = A:1
Thomas = A:2

I got a form comboxbox where both names are in.
When i press Birgitte i want a macro called BS_Opgave() to run and when i pres Thomas i want Macro TR_Opgave to run.

My problem is I'm not sure how to connect the combox selection to a Macro in the VBA editor. I'm acutyally confused about everything in the editor about comboxing.

Comment: What kind of dropdown list is it? A data validation list? A combobox on a useform? A combobox in a worksheet?

Comment: A combobox on the worksheet. To be hornest I don't know what the best solution is. 
Compared to signing a macro to a button this seems very very confusing to me.

Comment: Ok my next question is... Is that combobox an ActiveX control or a Form Control?

Comment: Form control. I will try to update my first post, to maybe make a little bit more clear what i want. 2 minutes.

Comment: kool. One moment, creating a sample for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paste this code in a module. The Right Click on the Combobox and assign the macro `DropDown1_Change` to it :) And you are done.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropDown1_Change()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
        Select Case .List(.Value)
            Case "Birgitte": BS_Opgave
            Case "Thomas": TR_Opgave
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Sub BS_Opgave()
    MsgBox "You selected Birgitte"
End Sub

Sub TR_Opgave()
    MsgBox "You selected Thomas"
End Sub
```

**ASSUMPTIONS**

I am assuming the following

- The name of the combobox is "Drop Down 1"
- The combobox is in "Sheet1"

Comment: Thanks a million. Now it's working like a charm :)
That was the most simplified solution I've seen so far!